# Wrong output for loop in Python

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

For input path basename is this format for example.: "MaxTemp_1910-01_ACTUAL.txt". Code I have:

```
def data(path):
for files in [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(path)]:
    str1 = ''.join(files)
    new = re.split('_|-', str1)
    cat=new[0]
    year=new[1]
    month=new[2]

    print cat
    print year
    print month
```

print output of function is correct:

```
MaxTemp
1910
01
MaxTemp
1910
02
MaxTemp
1921
02
```

However when I call this function later it only gives the latest values (output: MaxTemp, 1921, 02) and not all the values previously shown to me. What do I change to make it output all of the values?

Comment: Wouldn't the result of `glob.glob(path)` depend on `path`? You might want to look at what `path` is each time the function is called.

Comment: @DavidK path uses wildcards and defined as "/home/lh/workspace/PythonSpark/input/*/*". Is it because I cannot do recursive on this?

Comment: I only have Python 3.5 installed, but glob.glob('pathonmycomputer/*/*') seems to work fine and gives me the same results each time when I do it several times in a row. That's why I wanted to verify what `path` is on _each call individually_ to make sure it's really the same input every time.

Comment: why doing str1 = ''.join(files) ? Isn't *files* actually already one basename, i.e. a string ? ''.join(files) will just split all its chars and then join them back, i.e. it's a no-op. I think you should rename your loop variable to singular and remove the join operation.